# CSS issue on a page

Tags: html, css, layout

Please have a look at http://just2test.in/smokestore/products.php?Show=1&cat=1&page=3

The first row of products are fine, but second row of products does not align with 1st row.so instead of 4 products in a row, it shows only one.
3rd row shows 3 products and 4th row shows 2.

Can any body help me ?

Comment: Please post your code here, not as a link to an external site. Use the Stack Snippets feature to make the code executable.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close because your question doesn't meet SO standards. However, the problem is that your fourth item is 2px shorter than the rest, possibly due to a smaller-than-standard image. Set minimum heights on the appropriate elements to maintain uniformity.

(Kinda funny how many 420 sites have come up on SO lately. Strangely, my work network didn't block this one.)